What if a CP/PARAFAC tensor decomposition can be further decomposed, "recursively"?
Standard CP/PARAFAC decomposition:
A tensor $\mathcal{T}$ in shape $(I_1,\dots,I_N)$ is produced by $N$ matrices $\mathbf{A}^{(1)}, \dots, \mathbf{A}^{(N)}$ where each $\mathbf{A}^{(n)}$ is in shape $(I_n, D)$, i.e., they align in column sizes. $\mathcal{T}$ is the sum over their column vectors' outer products:
$$\mathcal{T}_{i_1,\dots,i_N} = \sum_{d=1}^{D} \prod_{n=1}^{N} \mathbf{A}^{(n)}_{i_n, d}.$$
Given $\mathcal{T}$, such a decomposition is unique (i.e., each of $\mathbf{A}^{(n)}$ is identifiable up to column permutation and scalings) if
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}{k(\mathbf{A}^{(n)})} \geq 2D+(N-1),$$
where $k(\cdot)$ denotes the Kruskal rank. This uniqueness result is given in e.g., Sidiropoulos, N.D. and Bro, R., 2000..

What if some $\mathbf{A}^{(n)}$ can be further "decomposed":
Let's consider only the last matrix $\mathbf{A}^{(N)}$. Suppose that $\mathbf{A}^{(N)}$ is reshaped from a tensor $\mathcal{A}$ (for simplicity we omit superscript $^{(N)}$ here) in shape $(I_N, J_1, \dots, J_M)$ with $D=\prod_{m=1}^{M}J_m$, and this tensor $\mathcal{A}$ contains further low rankness -- there exists $M$ matrices $\mathbf{B}^{(1)}, \dots, \mathbf{B}^{(M)}$, each $\mathbf{B}^{(m)}$ in shape $(J_m, I_N)$. $\mathcal{A}$ is produced by:
$$\mathcal{A}_{i,j_1,\dots,j_M} = \prod_{m=1}^{M} \mathbf{B}^{(m)}_{j_m, i}.$$
Now the question is, under which conditions are $\mathbf{A}^{(1)}, \dots, \mathbf{A}^{(N-1)}, \mathbf{B}^{(1)}, \dots, \mathbf{B}^{(M)}$ unique up to trivial indeterminacies?

Of course it's a simple case above, and actually each $\mathbf{A}^{(n)}$ may be reshaped from a tensor that can be further decomposed.
What is the name of this formulation? Something like "hierarchical/recursive/nested" CP? It's not Tucker, CANDELINC, INDSCAL, block-term, etc. either.
It seems quite natural though, so any reference studying on this formulation would help.
